# Return the name of object in method

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to coding, and I'm following this French tutorial that is basically making a RPG game used through console.

So I got a Character class in a `.cpp` file and `.h`, another `.h` `.cpp` couple of files for the weapons, and my main.

I got a function on my CPP file that's like this :

```
void Character::attack(Character &target)
{
    target.takeDamage(m_weapon.getDamage());
     
}
```

So far, in understand I'll use it in this way : `davids.attack(goliath)` and I made an alias so I can easily use the `takeDamage` function of my target using its alias.

but I'd like to add a console line like `David attacked Goliath and made X damages` in that function.
And it looks like I can't call another function like

```
string Character::getname 
{return name}
```

due to the fact I use 2 different characters.

Is there a way to get around that or should I get them both an alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Character class has field like `name` you can access the field in your method by using `this->name` (it will acces name of the object which called the method, in this case it is David) and the `target.name` will be "Goliath".

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is also how you call a method. Since OP mentioned having a getter `getName`, you would do `this->getName()` and `target.getName()`, respectively.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't notice the getter.

Comment: Thanks ! I got many other bugs to figure out, but  this seams to be the good direction ! may have failed somewhere else because     
`cout << goliath.getName();` 
does not return anything, so my mistakes surely comes from my class / object creation.

Comment: @Beebedibooh Try to avoid having more than one bug at a time by writing code in small chunks. Write a few lines, just enough to have one thing you can test. Compile it and resolve all errors and warnings. Test it. when you get exactly the behaviour you want  (and no other "sometimes" behaviours), you move on to the next few lines of code. With a few lines of code you won't have many errors and they are most likely to be in the lines you just added making finding them pretty easy. If you let bugs build up, they gang up on you and become much, MUCH harder to solve.

Comment: @user4581301 : Yes, i realize that now .. but i didn't expected to be unable to call my object name before i actually tryed it in my attack method. And now modifying stuff is a lot harder ! i guess i'm learning !

Answer (score -1):

If C++17 is available to you I recommend using CRTP.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template <typename Derived>
class Character{
    static constexpr std::string_view CName = "Character";

public:
    constexpr const std::string_view& getName() { return Derived::CName; }

    template<typename K>
    void Attack(Character<K>& Target) {
        std::cout << getName() << " attacked " << Target.getName() << "\n";
    }
};

class David : public Character<David>{
    public:

    static constexpr std::string_view CName = "David";
};

class Goliath : public Character<Goliath>{
    public:
    static constexpr std::string_view CName = "Goliath";
};

int main(int a, char** argv){

    David d;
    Goliath g;

    d.Attack(g);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This seems like pretty considerable overkill. Why would we even want `David` and `Goliath` to be separate classes entirely instead of different instances of a single `Character` class?

Comment: There are at least 2 optimizations points here, small class footprint and no virtual calls. This has a smaller usage range than the virtual call, but if it is usable will yield better performance.

Comment: Well, first, considering the code isn't functioning at all, it seems premature to try to rewrite it in a more complicated but possibly more performant fashion. And second, _what_ virtual calls to replace? Nobody but you has proposed any kind of inheritance as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I gave an alternative answer, not only for the requester (Beebedibooh) but for people that might came across and this solution might fit their requirements.

Comment: @BalanNarcis : thanks for the advice, but as i'm pretty new to coding, i'm not sure i'm understunding what you're proposing .. i should make another class that is basically a copy of mine, but with public attributes ?

Comment: I see. I recommend learning template programming in c++. Follow that with some metaprogramming practices and you'll be top notch :). Please follow this link and tinker with the code above [ https://godbolt.org/z/Gxn1bsqnq ]. As for what i did in the example its called CRTP(Curiously recurring template pattern) here is the wiki link [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern].

Comment: Learn the C++ fundamentals before attacking template metaprogramming (TMP). TMP is pretty close to a language unto itself, so if you try to pick it up too soon, you're learning two languages at once. Since using TMP effectively requires you to know the C++ fundamentals, which to start with is kind of obvious.